# Android: Saving an int over approx. 50 000 in value causes it to lose that value when its read.

Tags: android

I'm writing a game and the player gets coins after each round. The total amount of coins is written to a file at the end of the round using the following code: (the code works for everything I need saved and after thorough testing not what I think the issue is)

```
public static void writeToFile(String file, int[] info)
{
    try
    {

        File file1 = new File(context.getFilesDir(), file);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1);

        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
        {

            fw.write(info[i]);

        }

        fw.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Now, the issue I'm having is that when I read the value of coins saved, whether it be after reloading the game, or by setting up a reload button, *if* (the number of coins required is random... very strange) the int value is around 50 000 or any value above 50 000 than the reloaded/read value of the coins from the file is reduced by a random amount (EX: sometimes it will go from being written at 67 654, to being read at 13).

The code I'm using to read the file is:

```
public static int[] inputFromFile(String file, int size)
{

    int[] info = new int[size];
    int index = 0;

    try {

        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + file));
        int temp;

        if (buf != null)
        {

            temp = buf.read();

            while (temp != -1)
            {

                info[index] = temp;
                temp = buf.read();
                index++;

            }

            buf.close();

        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {

        File file1 = new File(context.getFilesDir(), file);
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return info;

}
```

The classes are public static as they are accessed from various actives, and they are also used for multiple file outputs and inputs. I have done quite a bit (few hours) of debugging and after all of this I have figured out that it only happens upon the value being read from the file (as the variable does get its value changed properly before it is written to the file).I also tested it with another value/variable and the same problem occurred.

All other variables that are written to the file and read from the file have their proper values as long as they are under approximately 50 000.

All the variables are public static int.

Thanks for the help, and if anything else is needed to help just ask and ill edit the post!

Comment: I would recommend you to store it out of the game's directory for example in an online database or something to avoid cheating... also to avoid such error :)

Comment: Would do so if I knew how to lol. First project/having some fun programming over the summer so not too worried about cheating or anything, but that is a good idea. I'll try to learn how to for my next project (:

Comment: it's much easer and safer and most of games compines are using that.. you should use that if you're planning to jump to the next level.. just get an online server and use what language you perfer e.g:PHP, ASP, Python..etc to create an api connection between your game and the server..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value is 65535, not about 50,000, and the reason is that you are reading and writing chars, not ints.

You should be using `DataOutputStream.writeInt()` and `DataInputStream.readInt()`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! What does the DataOutputStream write to? cause I'm unsure of how to direct it to a specific file.

Comment: Never mind, figured out the answer to my comment (:  , Again thank you for the help, I'm decently new so the knowledge will definitely help later!